# Can't force quit application even in Activity Monitor (AnyTransToolHelpers)

Tags: activity-monitor, force-quit

I installed AnyTrans. I uninstalled it soon after. But, I can't seem to get my mac to stop running some helper that seems to somehow be leftover.

[image]

I have tried:

1. going into activity monitor, selecting "AnyTransToolHelpers", clicking the "X" and selecting "Force Quit"
2. Restarting my computer

In case this is any help, when I double-click "AnyTransToolHelpers" it opens a window and then I can select an "Open Files and Ports" tab which shows the following:

```
cwd
/
txt
/Users/myComputerName/Library/Application Support/com.imobie.AnyTrans/AnyTransToolHelpers.app/Contents/MacOS/AnyTransToolHelpers
txt
/Library/Preferences/Logging/.plist-cache.TWfVjDjS
txt
/usr/share/icu/icudt68l.dat
txt
/private/var/db/timezone/tz/2021a.3.0/icutz/icutz44l.dat
txt
/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemAppearance.bundle/Contents/Resources/SystemAppearance.car
txt
/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemAppearance.bundle/Contents/Resources/FauxVibrantDark.car
txt
/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemAppearance.bundle/Contents/Resources/VibrantDark.car
txt
/private/var/db/analyticsd/events.whitelist
txt
/private/var/db/mds/messages/502/se_SecurityMessages
txt
/usr/lib/libobjc-trampolines.dylib
txt
/Users/myComputerName/Library/Caches/com.iMobie.AnyTransToolHelpers/Cache.db-shm
txt
/usr/lib/dyld
txt
/private/var/folders/k3/sjq7sq2n5wvfb3qwzkglwxr40000gp/0/com.apple.LaunchServices.dv/com.apple.LaunchServices-3027-v2.csstore
txt
/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemAppearance.bundle/Contents/Resources/DarkAqua.car
txt
/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemAppearance.bundle/Contents/Resources/Assets.car
txt
/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemAppearance.bundle/Contents/Resources/FunctionRowAppearance.car
txt
/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemAppearance.bundle/Contents/Resources/Aqua.car
0
/dev/null
1
/dev/null
2
/dev/null
3
/Users/myComputerName/Library/Application Support/com.iMobie.AnyTransToolHelpers/AnyTransToolHelpers/LogsFolder/log-FD11C7.txt
4
/Users/myComputerName/Library/Caches/com.iMobie.AnyTransToolHelpers/Cache.db
5
/Users/myComputerName/Library/Caches/com.iMobie.AnyTransToolHelpers/Cache.db-wal
6
/Users/myComputerName/Library/Caches/com.iMobie.AnyTransToolHelpers/Cache.db-shm
7
```

**Is there any other way to get this AnyTransToolHelpers application to stop running?**

Comment: https://www.imobie.com/faq/anytrans-faqs.htm#quescate2

Answer (score 1):

If you are very lucky, empty Trash and reboot.  But, assuming that doesn't work, let's first stop it running which you know how to do in Activity Monitor.

Now to stop it running after a reboot. Make sure that Finder has view hidden files enabled (Hold Shift and Command and press the dot key). Look in these locations (and delete if found) anything that looks like AnyTrans:

1. ~/Library/LaunchAgents.
2. /Library/LaunchAgents and /Library/LaunchDaemons (you will likely need your admin password to delete anything here).
3. And in System Preference > Users & Groups > Login Items to see if it is being started there.

Now  remove artefacts left over from install:

1. The file open list in your question is a good starting point and is probably sufficient.

Finally empty the trash and reboot.

Now, hopefully, it won't start again.

In future, don't uninstall by just deleting the application. Use an uninstall application like [AppCleaner](https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/).

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same. Got rid of that by following these steps:

1. Go to `~/Library/Application Support`(via finder or terminal)
2. Delete any folders starting with com.imobie:
   [image]
3. Empty Trash
4. Restart